# ASP.NET MVC 2: Using ImageRouteHandler to work on server subdirectory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 project where I built a custom ImageRouteHandler, following this blog:
http://www.phpvs.net/2009/08/06/aspnet-mvc-how-to-route-to-images-or-other-file-types/

It all works great when I test it locally, but after I deploy it to a subdirectory of the root folder on my webserver... all the images are still referenced by: www.blabla.com/Images instead of using the subdirectory of the project.

How can I correct this? I'm guessing I have to add something like ApplicationPath before the Images/{filename} in my Global.asax.cs:
routes.Add("ImagesRoute",
                 new Route("Images/{filename}", new ImageRouteHandler()));

I just can't seem to figure out how. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you part of your view code that creates the <img> tag where the failure occurs? Generally this sort of thing is experienced when you move to a virtual directory and the relative URL is not rendered correctly.

Comment: <a href="/Images/patio20_woongroep.png" target="_blank"><img src="/Images/patio20_woongroep.png" width="550px" alt="" /></a>

That's what I use to access a certain image...

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by writing a custom ImageHelper class:

```
public static string ImgUrl(string applicationPath, string filename)
{
  if (applicationPath == "/")
  {
    return "/Images/" + filename;
  }
  else
  {
    return applicationPath + "/Images/" + filename;
  }
}
```

And access images in my views like so:

```
<%= ImageHelper.ImgUrl(Request.ApplicationPath, "test.png") %>
```